# Finite group with the property that every element of order a power of $p$ is contained in a conjugacy class of size a power of $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $G$ be a finite group with the property (*)
>    that every element of order a power of $p$ is contained in a conjugacy
>   class of size a power of $p$.
>
> i) If $p\mid\left|G\right|$ prove that $G$ has a central subgroup $Z$
>    of order $p$.
>
> ii) If $Z$ is as above, prove that $G/Z$ has property (*).
>
> iii) Deduce that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal.

I don't have idea to start. Help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Must the Sylow $p$-subgroup even be a direct factor?

Comment: Yes, I think you can prove that by applying induction to $G/Z$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Since nontrivial $p$-groups have nontrivial centres, we can choose $g \in Z(P)$ of order $p$. Then $P \le C(g)$, so the conjugacy class of $g$ has order dividing $|G|/|P|$, which is coprime to $p$, so it must be $1$ by hypothesis, and hence $g \in Z(G)$. In fact $Z(P) \le Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ does not divide $|G|$ the only element of order power of $p$ is the identity, whose conjugacy class has order $1,$ which tells you absolutely nothing.

If there is an element of order power of $p,$ then there are some Sylow $p$-subgroups of order $p^k.$ Suppose there are $l$ of them. Analyze the the total number of non-identity elements and show that it is relatively prime to $p.$ Since the union of all elements of (nontrivial) prime power is a conjugacy invariant set, that means that some elements have conjugacy class of size $1,$ which means that they are central.

You can go on from there...

Comment: Distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups need not intersect trivially...

Comment: @user115654  can you offer an example?

Comment: @BettyMock: Not off the top of my head, but I believe the concept of "$p$-core" is relevant here

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug, changed to be more vague (but correct).

Comment: @BettyMock For the dihedral group of order $12$ presented as $\langle r, s \mid r^6 = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1}\rangle$, the Sylow 2-subgroups $\langle s, r^3 \rangle = \{1, s, r^3, sr^3\}$ and $\langle r^3, sr \rangle = \{1, r^3, sr, sr^4\}$ intersect non-trivially in $\{1, r^3\}$.

Comment: @JSwanson very nice and non-trivial answer.